# SQL Server 2016, Unexpected Result with Stored Procedure Execution

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am by no means a SQL expert.  I tend to build and test queries from other sample code that I find and learn in this way.  I have a stored procedure that I wrote to update customer pricing in two tables.  The gist of what should happen is that if the item and price level exist, it should update that item's price.  If it doesn't exist, I need it to insert a new record with that data.  When I executed this procedure, it updated every single record in the DB.  I would greatly appreciate some insight into best practice in formulating this conditional statement properly.  Thanks in advance.

```
USE [TEST]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[aUpdatePricingLevels]    Script Date: 5/2/2022 9:59:38 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE   PROCEDURE [dbo].[aUpdatePricingLevels]

@ItemNumber CHAR(31),
@PriceLevel CHAR(11),
@ToQuantity numeric(19, 5) = 999999999999,
@FromQuantity numeric(19, 5) = 1,
@UnitOfMeasure char(9) = 'EA',
@Price numeric(19, 5),
@Equivalency numeric(19, 5) = 1

AS

IF EXISTS(Select * FROM IV00108 WHERE ITEMNMBR like @ItemNumber and PRCLEVEL LIKE @PriceLevel)
    UPDATE IV00108 SET UOMPRICE= @Price  --THERE IS AN ISSUE HERE.  IT SET ALL PRICES. NEEDS A 
CONDITIONAL
    --PRINT'placeholder'

ELSE

INSERT INTO dbo.IV00108 (ITEMNMBR,PRCLEVEL,TOQTY,FROMQTY,UOFM,UOMPRICE,QTYBSUOM)
VALUES(@ItemNumber,@PriceLevel,@ToQuantity,@FromQuantity,@UnitOfMeasure,@Price,@Equivalency)


IF EXISTS(Select * FROM IV00107 WHERE ITEMNMBR like @ItemNumber and PRCLEVEL LIKE @PriceLevel)
    PRINT 'Record Exists, No Action Needed'
    ELSE
INSERT INTO dbo.IV00107 (ITEMNMBR,PRCLEVEL,UOFM,ROUNDHOW,ROUNDTO,UMSLSOPT,QTYBSUOM)
VALUES(@ItemNumber,@PriceLevel,@UnitOfMeasure,0,1,2,@Equivalency)
GO
```

Comment: There's no WHERE clause in your UPDATE statement which is means "update every row in the table".  You probably want the same WHERE clause as you have in the IF EXISTS.  Or, better yet, just move that WHERE CLAUSE to the UPDATE and remove the IF EXISTS.

Comment: *"it updated every single record in the DB"* if by DB you mean table (a table an object inside a database, and updating every row in every table in a database isn't easy), of course it did; there was no `WHERE` in your `UPDATE`. You use a `WHERE` in the `EXISTS` but then completely omit it in the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear.  It updated every row in that table as expected without a where statement.  I couldnt get past the syntax error when attempting to add a where statement to the update.  I will investigate further with the recommendations below

Comment: If you want help with the syntax error, post the syntax you tried and the exact error message you received.

Comment: Is item number really a string in your table? Why aren't you just using MERGE?

Answer (score 3):

You're saying:

```
IF EXISTS (rows where multiple things are true)
  UPDATE the whole table (no filter here).
```

A much better pattern *even if that logic were correct* would be:

```
UPDATE dbo.IV00108
  SET UOMPRICE = @Price
  WHERE ITEMNMBR like @ItemNumber 
    and PRCLEVEL LIKE @PriceLevel;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
  INSERT ...
END
```

Why don't we want to say:

```
IF (a row with these conditions exists) 
  UPDATE the row with these conditions
```

? Because it's twice the work (why locate the row(s) twice?), because it creates a scenario where you can have inconsistencies between them (like in this case), and - most importantly - because it introduces more opportunities for race conditions. See:

- [Please stop using this UPSERT anti-pattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern)

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I tried to add a where condition but it kept flagging incorrect syntax.  I will continue to investigate and read the link you provided.  Being newish to SQL, often these links provided by others add confusion not clarity to answers but I will continue to investigate.  Thank you for your feedback.  Also, I use LIKE not = because often we are only trying to match a few characters of a record not an exact string.  ie. "... LIKE 'HD%'"

Comment: @notionDesign Then you shouldn't be passing those as e.g. `CHAR(31)` - it certainly implies you expect a direct match and not wildcards (partly because there is inconsistent behavior re: respecting and ignoring trailing spaces).

Comment: Why even use an @@rowcount check when SQL Server has MERGE?

Comment: @MatBailie For [dozens of reasons, actually](https://sqlblog.org/merge). Also `MERGE` is kind of overkill for either updating or inserting _one row_, IMHO, and in spite of common misconceptions, is _not_ a single operation. The row either exists or it doesn't; the logic isn't complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You have a where on your exists but not on your update
Here maybe indenting helps...

```
IF EXISTS(
      Select * 
      FROM IV00108 
      WHERE ITEMNMBR like @ItemNumber and PRCLEVEL LIKE @PriceLevel
)
UPDATE IV00108 SET UOMPRICE= @Price  
WHERE ITEMNMBR like @ItemNumber and PRCLEVEL LIKE @PriceLevel)
```

**UPDATE**

*As Arron says in another answer -- better to use @@rowcount*